# ANTLR4 Grammar extraneous / mismatched input error

Tags: regex, antlr4

I would like to declare a string which contains any character in my grammar,
but doesn't works.

Here is my grammar:
[Syrius.g4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr2W4.png)

When I run it, I got the following error:

```
$ grun Syrius program
string test = "testString";
line 1:6 extraneous input ' ' expecting ID
line 1:11 mismatched input ' ' expecting ';'
```

What could be the problem with the grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

Your token `STR : .;` will match any character. `STR` is defined before `WS` lexeme thus, it will consume all the whitespace characters instead. When parsing `string test = "testString";` the lexer will produce sequence of these tokens: `string`, `STR`, `ID`, ... and so on. But the parser is looking for a `declaration` rule which consists of `string`, `ID`, ... tokens.

### Solution

Define `STR` token properly. Use this token in `declaration` parser rule:

```
STR : '"' .*? '"';
// (...)
declaration
    : 'int' ID ('=' INTEGER)? ';'
    | 'string' ID ('=' STR)? ';'
    ;
```